# Keystrokes are much faster when not using a window manager. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and I've noticed that when I boot to say, recovery mode and without any window manager of any type, the keystrokes register instantly and yet when I use my normal window manager for almost anything like typing in a web browser, text editor, etc, there's more of a slight delay.

Does anyone know the real reason behind this or could this be the type of hardware I'm using?

Comment: http://danluu.com/term-latency/ and http://danluu.com/input-lag/ might be interesting reads. how much software bloat does your window manager bring?

Comment: Obviously you can fault code bloat. No matter how good the machine... Obviously you will feel it less in an high end i7 than in a Celeron, just to give a real example.